# How to replicate this code to upload video instead of image width Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to replicate a code i got that uploads images to a server ASP.NET web api but width videos instead, right now im trying to upload a .MOV video recorded from an iOS device but i dont really know how to modify my code to work with videos. This is the code that works and can upload images from the device. I've tried using the same code but instead of getting a image from img element i've gotten the video from video element without any further success.

```
function upload(){

var img = document.getElementById("insertedImg");
var dataURL = getBase64Image(img);   
var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
var data = new FormData();
data.append("canvasImage", blob); 


$.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url: 'http://testwebsite.net/api/upload',
 data: data,
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
 success: function(data) {    
 alert('success');   
},
 error: function(response){
 alert('error');
} 
}); 
}
```

And the getBase64 function

```
function getBase64Image(img) {

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;


var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  

return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

}
```

And dataURItoBlob function

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {

var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

If anyone know how i can modify this code to work with videos i'd highly appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/5378743

Comment: You don't need to manually encode the file at all - use `FormData` to do it for you. You can then deal with the storing the file on the server as required. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information. It is titled as being for MVC, but the code works exactly the same way in WebAPI